# Ruby Hash: how to filter value (an array) and return?

Tags: ruby, hash

I've been looking for a way to filter values in Ruby Hash (the value of my Hash is an array of Hashes).

My problem:

I have below Hash:

```
expanded_addresses_map = 
{
  :t2p=>[],
  :non_t2p=>[
    {:recipient=>"steve sun", :email=>"ada@gmail.com"},
    {:recipient=>"sophie yan", :email=>"sophie@gmail.com"},
    {:recipient=>"eason", :email=>"eason@eason12325467com"}]
}
```

What I wanted to do is to filter out the hashes in the value of the outside hash that has invalid email addresses filtering by my email regex, the best I could reach is below:

```
expanded_addresses_map.reject do |k, v|
  v.reject do |address|
    address[:email] !~ ::Recipient::EMAILS_REGEX
  end
end
```

So what I don't understand is that the above returns me `{}`.

But when I run below:

```
expanded_addresses_map[:non_t2p].reject do |address|
  address[:email] !~ ::Recipient::EMAILS_REGEX
end
```

it could correctly return this:

```
[
  {:recipient=>"steve sun", :email=>"ada@gmail.com"},
  {:recipient=>"sophie yan", :email=>"sophie@gmail.com"}
]
```

What I wanted to get is below:

```
expanded_addresses_map = 
{
  :t2p=>[],
  :non_t2p=>[
    {:recipient=>"steve sun", :email=>"ada@gmail.com"},
    {:recipient=>"sophie yan", :email=>"sophie@gmail.com"}
  ]
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reject` always returns an object, so nesting a `reject` inside another one does not give the expected result

So the code

```
expanded_addresses_map.reject do |k, v|
  v.reject do |address|
    address[:email] !~ ::Recipient::EMAILS_REGEX
  end
end
```

Is logically equivalent to

```
expanded_addresses_map.reject do |k, v|
  true
end
```

To filter out, `map` the value of the hash and filter inside:

```
expanded_addresses_map.map do |k, v|
  values = v.reject do |address|
    address[:email] !~ ::Recipient::EMAILS_REGEX
  end
  [k, values]
end.to_h
```

This will return a hash with the same format as `expanded_addresses_map` but without the invalid emails

Comment: @FisherCoder you're welcome ;-) I figured it would be more helpful to explain why your solution did not work, I hope you have a better understanding now ^.^

Answer (score 2):

```
expanded_addresses_map.values.flatten.reject do |address|
  address[:email] !~ ::Recipient::EMAILS_REGEX
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
expanded_addresses_map.map {|k, v| v.reject { |address| address[:email] !~ ::Recipient::EMAILS_REGEX }}
```

You will have to iterate over each items using `map` in the array of hashes and reject items based on the `reject` conditions.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish to modify (mutate) `expanded_addresses_map` you could write the following.

```
expanded_addresses_map.merge(expanded_addresses_map) { |k,v,_|
  k==:non_t2p ? v.select { |h| h[:email].match? ::Recipient::EMAILS_REGEX } : o[k] }
```

This uses the form of [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that employs a block to determine the values of the keys that are present in both hashes being merged, which here is all keys. See the doc for an explanation of the values assigned to the three block variables `k`, `v` and `_`. (The choice of the underscore for the third local variable--a valid name--tells the reader that it is not used in the block calculation).